# REST naming conventions JOIN

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I have basic get functions:

```
app.get('/v1/example', (req, res, next) => {
Connection.query('SELECT * FROM Table1', function (error, results, fields) {...

app.get('/v1/example/:id', (req, res, next) => {...

app.get('/v1/example2', (req, res, next) => {
Connection.query('SELECT * FROM Table2', function (error, results, fields) {...

app.get('/v1/example2/:id', (req, res, next) => {...
```

When i do JOIN it looks like this:

```
app.get('/v1/...', (req, res, next) =>{
Connection.query('SELECT * FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.TestID = Table2.TestID', function (error, results, fields) {...
```

What is the REST naming convention for my last route? Does it have to be /v1/example3 or /v1/example1/example2 or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

REST Api endpoint naming has noting to do with SQL query. It is more about what you are trying to achieve by the endpoint. Here is a very useful [guideline by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design) about api design.

Comment: This "guide" just sums up the inaccuracies in modern REST architecture design by propagating certain believes that do not necessarily hold true when you'd ask Fielding about his take on that matter. I.e. a true client in a REST architecture does not care whether the URI is termed `.../orders` or `.../create-order`  as it does not analyze the URI itself but rely on standardized or well-specified link-relation names. Also, their take on versioning is surely not the same as [Fielding's view](https://www.infoq.com/articles/roy-fielding-on-versioning/) on it. Use that "guide" therefore with caution

Answer (score 0):

i guess answer should be 
`'/v1/example/example2'`

cause it saying that you connecting with both table1 + table 2

Comment: The problem is that  the get function does not work when i use `'/v1/example/example2'`. It seems like i need to change 'example', then it would work again. Why can't i use the endpoint '`/v1/example'` with `/example2` added?

Answer (score -1):

> What is the REST naming convention for my last route? Does it have to be /v1/example3 or /v1/example1/example2 or anything else?

Anything you want.

[REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) doesn't care what spellings you use for your resource identifiers.  See [Fielding, 2008](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven).  From the perspective of the general purpose components, the URI is just an opaque identifier, analogous to a surrogate key or a UUID.  Any spelling consistent with the production rules defined in RFC 3986 are *fine*.

```
app.get('/v1/124003d7-bca4-4a1c-ad3f-5e5e7a900fba', (req, res, next) =>{
    Connection.query(
        'SELECT * FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.TestID = Table2.TestID',
        function (error, results, fields) {...
```

That's perfectly satisfactory.

We care about URI spellings for the same reason that we care about variable names; the *human beings* who need to read them need additional semantic context to orient themselves.
For example, if you are reading a web log, `/v1/124003d7-bca4-4a1c-ad3f-5e5e7a900fba` doesn't help you orient yourself.

The URI identifies a resource, which is to say information that can be named ([Fielding, 2000](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1)).  So if you are looking for a human readable spelling for the identifier, you should be thinking about the information being returned to the client -- in this case, the report that you construct from the result set, rather than thinking about how that report is produced.

In effect, this is information hiding -- the "how" is hidden, and can be changed without impacting the consumer.